# How to send push notification to Specific user in Web-push?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, web-push

I have an existing web site , i just need to push notification to the site, for that i am using
Nodejs web-push package , I can able to receive notifications but i need to change it to **User Specific**,

**For Example i want to send the notifications for the users based on the country**

This is my code

client.js

```
const publicVapidKey = 'xxxxxx';

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  console.log('Registering service worker');

  run().catch(error => console.error(error));
}
function urlBase64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
  const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
  const base64 = (base64String + padding)
    .replace(/-/g, '+')
    .replace(/_/g, '/');

  const rawData = window.atob(base64);
  const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
    outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return outputArray;
}

async function run() {
  console.log('Registering service worker');
  const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.
    register('worker.js');
  console.log('Registered service worker');

  console.log('Registering push');
  const subscription = await registration.pushManager.
    subscribe({
      userVisibleOnly: true,
      // The `urlBase64ToUint8Array()` function is the same as in
      // https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push#using-vapid-key-for-applicationserverkey
      applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicVapidKey)
    });
    // subscription.user = $('.header-user-name').find('span').text();
  console.log('Registered push');

  console.log('Sending push');
  await fetch('http://localhost:3000/subscribe?user='+$('.header-user-name').find('span').text(), {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(subscription),
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
  console.log('Sent push');
}
```

Worker.js

```
console.log('Loaded service worker!');

self.addEventListener('push', ev => {
  const data = ev.data.json();
  console.log('Got push', data);

  ev.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
    body: 'Hello, World!',
    registration_ids: [$('.header-user-name').find('span').text()]
    icon: 'http://mongoosejs.com/docs/images/mongoose5_62x30_transparent.png'
  }));

});
```

Server Code (localhost:3000/push)

```
app.get('/push',function(req,res) {

  const payload = JSON.stringify({ title: 'Hello '+ user.name +' ' + req.query.title,  });

  console.log(req.query);
  console.log("yahooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");

  webpush.sendNotification(newSubscription, payload).catch(error => {
    console.error(error.stack);
  });
  res.send({result : 'Success'});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long gap, I got a solution for this problem.

Steps to be followed:

1. Create an ExpressJs api to store the user subscription in to a database.
2. Get the user based on countries from database (you can use your own backend language I have chosen Nodejs).
3. Create an api which can send push notifications using given parameter like (Country, Users, Etc).

Happy Coding.

Comment: Can you elaborate this please.

Comment: @AnuragGupta You have to store your Web Push subscriptions in a database for future reference when you want to send notifications to users that has subscribed. Now what Gopinath says is, that you have to add a e.g. "Country" field that subscription entry, and then you can do something like: Get all users from DB where "Country = Germany" and then send notifications to them.

Comment: @AnuragGupta Is every subscription is unique?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the users' IPs to look up their countries by using a service like [ip-api.com](https://ip-api.com/). After you get the country info, you can include it in your request body along with the push subscription object and send to your backend. So, you will have the opportunity to segment your subscribers and send them push notifications with different content.